# Both arguments are correct

Tags: idioms, phrase-requests

I wrote a paper about two opposing arguments. My conclusion was that the two arguments may be correct.

Is there an idiom or phrase that means two opposite things may be correct, independent of each other?

Comment: You might use "Where Extremes Meet"—a common expression for the uncommon phenomenon in which things that seem to be going in opposite directions end up coming together (as if in curvilinear space).

Comment: This site isn't a brainstorming service.

Comment: i think you meant "independent" rather than "interdependent", judging from the context of your question.  if this is incorrect, please rollback my edit.

Comment: i'm reminded of the blind men and the elephant story. each is touching a different part of the elephant and arguing with the others that he is correct, when they're all describing different parts of the same thing.

Comment: I don't see how this question is substantively different from the hundreds of single-word requests  and phrase requests that we entertain on this site every week. Is the problem here that the OP was impolitic enough to let slip that he or she had a practical reason for being interested in this particular phrase?

Answer (score 1):

One idiom that comes to mind is: [Agree to Disagree](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agree_to_disagree). This means that the two arguments respectfully disagree with each other, while preventing further argument, as neither will change the others' mind.

There is also "[Two Sides of the Same Coin](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/be+two+sides+of+the+same+coin)". This means that both arguments are closely connected and similar in what they are arguing.

Comment: i'm not sure the first suggestion meets the OP's intent, but the second is very relevant.  good choice!

Answer (score 0):

Are you describing a paradox?

Is there some sense in which both answers must be true?  If the arguments are totally contrary, perhaps it is a polar paradox.

Answer (score 0):

*Duel of the Dual Arguments*

[duality](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/duality)

> *noun (plural dualities)*
>
> 1. The quality or condition of being dual: *"the novel’s deep **duality** about human motive"*
>
>    1.1. *Mathematics* The property of two theorems, expressions, etc., being dual to each other.
>
>    1.2 *Physics* The quantum-mechanical property of being regardable as both a wave and a particle.
> 2. An instance of opposition or contrast between two concepts or two aspects of something; a dualism: "the photographs capitalize on the
>      **dualities** of light and dark, stillness and movement"

[duel](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/duel)

> *noun*
>
> 1. (*chiefly historical*) A contest with deadly weapons arranged between two people in order to settle a point of honor.
>
>    1.1 (*In modern use*) a contest or race between two parties: *"two eminent critics engaged in a verbal **duel**"*

[Wave–particle duality](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wave%E2%80%93particle_duality)

> is the concept that every elementary particle or quantic entity exhibits
>   the properties of not only particles, but also waves. It addresses the
>   inability of the classical concepts "particle" or "wave" to fully
>   describe the behavior of quantum-scale objects. As Einstein wrote:
>   *"It seems as though we must use sometimes the one theory and sometimes the other, while at times we may use either. We are faced
>   with a new kind of difficulty. We have two contradictory pictures of
>   reality; separately neither of them fully explains the phenomena of
>   light, but together they do".*